# How to set multiple values in a list using lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq

How to set multiple values of a list object, i am doing following but fails.

```
objFreecusatomization
.AllCustomizationButtonList
.Where(p => p.CategoryID == btnObj.CategoryID && p.IsSelected == true && p.ID == btnObj.ID)
.ToList()
.ForEach(x => x.BtnColor = Color.Red.ToString(),  );
```

In the end after comma i want to set another value.
What should be the expression, although i have only one record relevant.

Comment: Don't abuse LINQ to modify collection. It a query tool. Your approach is not more readable than a `foreach` but it's much less efficient.

Comment: Then it should be a lamda expression that can work? or any other way, or i need to loop it after taking object.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well personally I wouldn't write the code that way *anyway* - but you can just use a [statement lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx):

> A statement lambda resembles an expression lambda except that the statement(s) is enclosed in braces
>
> The body of a statement lambda can consist of any number of statements; however, in practice there are typically no more than two or three.

So the `ForEach` call would look like this:

```
.ForEach(x => {
    x.BtnColor = Color.Red.ToString();
    x.OtherColor = Color.Blue.ToString();
});
```

I would write a `foreach` loop instead though:

```
var itemsToChange = objFreecusatomization.AllCustomizationButtonList
     .Where(p => p.CategoryID == btnObj.CategoryID
                 && p.IsSelected
                 && p.ID == btnObj.ID);

foreach (var item in itemsToChange)
{
    item.BtnColor = Color.Red.ToString();
    item.OtherColor = Color.Blue.ToString();
}
```

(You can inline the query into the `foreach` statement itself, but personally I find the above approach using a separate local variable clearer.)

Comment: But i am sure the list will be holding one record, so i need to loop it with foreach.?

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: If you're sure it will only have one record, then you should use the methods like `FirstOrDefault`, `First`, `SingleOrDefault`, or `Single` (whichever is most applicable) rather than creating a list.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: This is the first you've mentioned of there only being one match. How were we meant to know that? Your original code was looping (with `ForEach`) so I naturally assumed you *needed* to loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yeah, if you got a reputation each time someone did that, then you'd have hit 600,000k reputation by now. :)

Comment: so you mean i should fetch with single statemebt to an object of that type and making changes and replace the object again.

Comment: is it coorect? will it make changes to collection as well
btnObject btnToChange = objFreecusatomization.AllCustomizationButtonList.Where(p => p.CategoryID == btnObj.CategoryID && p.IsSelected == true && p.ID == btnObj.ID).Single();
                    if (btnToChange != null)
                    {
                        btnToChange.IsSelected = false;
                        btnToChange.BtnColor = Color.Red.ToString();
                    }

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: To be honest, I'd probably just loop anyway - it does no harm, and it's simpler. If you really want to use that code, you should use `SingleOrDefault` instead of `Single` - `Single` will throw an exception if there aren't any matches.

Comment: i come to know to know you are author of a good book, does that help me with oops concept with good examples, then i would love to purchase that?

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: It's not really aimed at that - it's very specific to C#. Obviously I hope it would be useful to you, but it's not a general OO primer.

Comment: How can i learn strong oops that will help me to strongly put my project architecture? Please help me with this or giime idea, or book or any thing that is of great avail.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: I don't have any specific recommendations, I'm afraid.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36167/discussion-between-novicetodotnet-and-jon-skeet)